# jquery: how to open no of popup when user enter any number in text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, popup

I have one text box and one button.When user enter any digit in text box then click on button.Same digit no of popup should be open.

Please solve my problem  and if you know any link please share with me.

Please share your valuable  knowledge.

ThankYou

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please phrase your question to show what you have tried, and we can help you understand *why* it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to see when the button is clicked using the `$().click()` method. It will call a callback function which can open a popup. Within this method, get the value of the number in the text box (using the `document.getElementById('#textBox').value` and then use a for loop and use the `$('#popup').dialog()` function to open up the popups however many times.